# How to add filepath of assembly's sourcecode to step through external code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll, assemblies

If an unhandled exception occurs somewhere in an external DLL, Visual Studio pops up a dialog box that lets me select the path of its source code so that it can show me the exact line which caused the exception.  Once this file is open, I can set breakpoints, etc.

My question: how can I do this manually?  I'd like to set a breakpoint in some external code.